# Android + OPC, Bluetooth経由でカメラの電源を入れる方法

Tags: android, bluetooth, olympus-camerakit

Androidでアプリ開発をしているのですが、BLE経由でカメラの電源を入れる具体的な手順について教えて下さい。
ドキュメントや`wakeup()`を呼んだ時のエラーの内容から、現在のところ

```
camera = new OLYCamera();
camera.setContext(getApplicationContext());
camera.setConnectionListener(this);
oa_central=OACentralConfiguration.load();
btName=oa_central.getBleName();
btCode=oa_central.getBleCode();
```

と準備をし`startLeScan()`で以下の様なコールバックが呼ばれるようにしているのですが

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord){
        if (btName.equals(device.getName())){
            btAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
            btDevice = device;
            try {
                camera.setBluetoothDevice(btDevice);
                camera.setBluetoothPassword(btCode);
                camera.wakeup();
                camera.connect(OLYCamera.ConnectionType.BluetoothLE);
            } catch (OLYCameraKitException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "To connect to the camera is failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`wakeup()`時にGATTデバイスの接続に失敗というエラーが出たところで詰んでいます。

> I/OLYCameraLog: [INFO] [OLYCamera.java:1167:OLYCamera#wakeup]
>   D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 90:B6:86:08:41:12, auto: false
>   D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
>   D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=2ff089f3-5321-45a7-84a7-87b8166b47f7
>   D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 90:B6:86:08:41:12
>   D/BluetoothGatt: close()
>   D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=0
>   E/OLYCameraLog: [ERROR] [OLYCamera.java:1187:OLYCamera#wakeup] jp.co.olympus.camerakit.c: Failed to connect the GATT device.

`connectGatt()`を自前で呼んでみたり、`wakeup()`をBluetoothGattCallbackで実行してみたりと試してみましたが、エラー内容に変化がありません。
他にどのような手順が必要でしょうか？

### 追記

@ura14h さんの提案通りに`CountDownLatch`を使って`onLeScan()`後に`wakeup()`してみたところ、デバイスとの接続はうまくいくようになったように見えますが、新たなエラーが出るようになりました。

> I/OLYCameraLog: [INFO] [OLYCamera.java:1167:OLYCamera#wakeup]
>   D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 90:B6:86:08:41:12, auto: false
>   D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
>   （中略）
>   D/BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=90:B6:86:08:41:12 UUID=59168c27-b5cd-40c7-9ee0-f5ec2e927346 Status=0
>   E/OLYCameraLog: [ERROR] [OLYCamera.java:1228:OLYCamera#wakeup] jp.co.olympus.camerakit.i: The peripheral gave back status 1.
>   D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 90:B6:86:08:41:12

Comment: OPCサポートです。
ご質問ありがとうございます。

Camera Kitを調査しましたところ、不具合があることが判明いたしました。
ご不便をおかけいたします。
近日中にアップデート版を公開予定ですので、もうしばらくお待ちください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。SDKのアップデートを待つことにし、この場は解決済みとします。

Comment: Camera Kitをアップデートしたところ、wakeupに成功しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: アップデートいただきありがとうございます。ご不便をおかけし、申し訳ありませんでした。wakeupに成功したとのこと、安心いたしました。また、不具合をご指摘いただき、大変助かりました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

詰んでいる(ハングアップしている)ということは、Bluetoothの通信スレッド同士でデッドロックしているかもしれません。そうであればwakeup()とconnect()をonLeScan()の後に実行するようにした方が良いかも。手順としては

1. デバイス検索中フラグを準備(CountDownLatchとか)
2. onLeScan()でsetBluetoothDevice(),setBluetoothPassword()とそしてデバイス検索中フラグを解放する
3. startLeScan()する
4. デバイス検索中フラグが解放されるのをawait()で待つ
5. 待ちから正しく抜けてきたらwakeup()とconnect()

という流れです。